# maximum reasonable sample size

Tags: confidence-interval, mean, sample-size

I'm supposed to recommend a sample size for a nation wide measure. The population is at least several million.

The objective is to calculate a monetary average.
Last year, a sample size of 900 was used, and the sample average was 12, while the standard deviation of the average, as in
[image]

As I understand it, if I were to aim for a 95% confidence interval and a 5% margin of error, the formula would be:
[image]

But this leads to roughly n = 40,000, if I use that sigma value, which is over what is feasible.

So this brings me to two questions:
Is the computation completely wrong because I'm using a sigma that is estimated on a sample size that is too low?
Is it safe to say, a lower sample size, such as 10,000 would be fine in all cases?

Comment: Question for thought: does the formula you have for $n$ ask for the standard deviation of the average (aka the standard error), or the standard deviation of _the samples_? They are quite different quantities.

Comment: I think it is the standard error. If it were the standard deviation of the samples, the numbers would be huge. In my data here, I have standard deviation of the sample = 78 and standard error = 2.6.